# Usar tecla de función mediante HotKey en formularios hijos

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Tengo un formulario principal llamado index.xhtml y dentro de él llamo a formularios hijos mediante `<ui:include>`.

El problema es que cuando cambio entre un formulario hijo a otro, la primera vez funciona la tecla f6 del formulario hijo pero cuando cambio a otro formulario hijo para que me funcione la tecla f6 tengo que refrescar la página mediante f5.

Necesito utilizar la tecla de función f6, en los diferentes formularios hijos mediante `<p:hotkey bind="f6">`, sin tener que pulsar f5 (refrescar página) cada vez que cambio el formulario en la página principal.

Alguien podría ayudarme por favor?

---------------------------index.xhtml-----------------------:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    </f:facet>        
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p:layout fullPage="true">

    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="150" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
        <h1>Madeline<br>shop</br></h1>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
        Zapraszamy do odwiedzania naszego biura!
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Menu" collapsible="true">
        <h:form>
            <p:menu>
                <f:ajax render="@all" immediate="true">                        
                    <p:menuitem value="index_hijo_1" action="#{pageBean.setName('index_hijo7_1.xhtml')}" update=":content" />
                    <p:menuitem value="index_hijo7_2" action="#{pageBean.setName('index_hijo7_2.xhtml')}" update=":content" />                        
                </f:ajax>
            </p:menu>

            <h:panelGroup>                                                            
            <!--<p:panel id="panel" header="Form" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  -->                                                  
            <!--<h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2"> -->
                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Página:" />
                <!--<p:inputText id="name" size="10" required="true" value="documentC" binding="#{input1}" />   -->      
                <p:inputText id="name" size="10" required="true" value="index_hijo1.xhtml" binding="#{input1}" />               
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{pageBean.setName(input1.value)}" update=":content" />      
            <!--</h:panelGrid> -->
            <!--</p:panel> -->
            </h:panelGroup>

        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <br></br><br></br>
        <p:panel id="content">
            <ui:include src="#{pageBean.name}" />
        </p:panel>       
    </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>

</h:body>

</html>
```

-----------------------------PageBean.java:

```
package com.grupo.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.NoneScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
@ManagedBean
//@RequestScoped
//@ViewScoped
@SessionScoped
public class PageBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of PageBean
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//private String name="/main_pages/mainpage.xhtml";
private String name="documentA.xhtml";

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

-----------------------------index_hijo7_1.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"> 
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>     
        <!--<h:outputScript name="js/application.js" />-->
        <h:form>                
            <p:panel>                
                <p:growl id="index_hijo7_1_msgs1" showDetail="true"/>                        
                <p:hotkey bind="f6" update="index_hijo7_1_msgs1" actionListener="#{hotkeyView.save2}"/>                   

                <p:outputLabel value="Estoy en index_hijo7_1. Pulsa crtl+alt+s o f6" />
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

------------------------index_hijo7_2.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"> 
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>     
        <!--<h:outputScript name="js/application.js" />-->
        <h:form>                
            <p:panel>                
                <p:growl id="index_hijo7_2_msgs1" showDetail="true"/>                         
                <p:hotkey bind="f6" update="index_hijo7_2_msgs1" actionListener="#{hotkeyView.save4}"/>                   

                <p:outputLabel value="Estoy en index_hijo7_2. Pulsa crtl+alt+s o f6" />
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

-----------------------------------HotkeyView.java:

```
package com.grupo.hijo7.bean;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean

public class HotkeyView implements Serializable{
/**
 * Creates a new instance of HotkeyView
 */   

public HotkeyView() {
}

}
public void save2() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Success", "Llamado desde index_hijo7_1"));
}

public void save4() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Success", "Llamado desde index_hijo7_2"));
}

}
```

Comment: ¡Por favor, no grites!